# Talend writing file names from a list to a file for process completion

Tags: talend

My job has following steps:
- Connect to ftp location
- Download compressed files
- Uncompress files to different folder
- Delete compressed files
- Write file names to a tracking file

ftpConnection -OnComponentOk--> ftpList-Iterate--> ftpGet -Iterate--> fileList-Iterate--> fileUnarchive-Iterate--> fileDelete

Question is where can i write the uncompressed filenames to the tracking file. When i try to Iterate from fileUnarchive to fileOutputDelimited it does not
allow me, similarly if i want to add a map from fileDelete it does not allow me. Do i need a map or can i make use of the global variable somehow?

One way i can do it getting it after ftpGet but i would prefer to do it at a latter stage (after unarchiving or deletion) so i don't update the file if the 
process fails at one of these steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with tfiledelete-->oncomponentok-->tfixedflowinput(here you can use the same global variable which contains current file name from tfilelist)-->(mainflow)-=->tfileoutputdelimeted...